# Find the summation of forces between all possible pairs of points?

Tags: c++, algorithm, mathematical-optimization

There are `n` points with each having two attributes:

**1.** Position (from axis)

**2.** Attraction value (integer)

Attraction force between two points A & B is given by:

```
Attraction_force(A, B) = (distance between them) * Max(Attraction_val_A, Attraction_val_B);
```

Find the summation of all the forces between all possible pairs of points?

I tried by calculating and adding forces between all the pairs

```
for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
    for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
        force += abs(P[i].pos - P[j].pos) * max(P[i].attraction_val, P[j].attraction_val);
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
Points            P1 P2 P3
Points distance:  2  3  4
Attraction Val:   4  5  6

Force = abs(2 - 3) * max(4, 5) + abs(2 - 4) * max(4, 6) + abs(3 - 4) * max(5, 6) = 23
```

But this takes **O(n^2)** time, I can't think of a way to reduce it further!!

Comment: What makes you think you can make it any better?

Comment: coz the online judge is giving me timeout for large test cases, I think there must be some optimal solution!

Comment: could you paste a link to this problem if it is online and public?

Comment: it was an interview question, so the link is expired now. Well, It seems impossible to reduce it ..but I think it can be perhaps ..mathematically!

Comment: I believe this question will be much better fit for [CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) website. Note that cross-posting is discouraged, so I'd suggest deleting this question and posting same one on CS.

Comment: @yeputons I think it's fine here. There is some overlap in the scope of the two sites.

Comment: @Dukeling added an example

Comment: Scheme of a solution: sort all points by their attraction value; add them one-by-one; for each point you have to quickly calculate sum of distances to all previously added points, that can be done using any online Range Sum Query problem solution (all points to the left are not really different); then for each newly added you just multiply that sum of distances by its attraction value and add to the answer.

Comment: @yeputons can you write an answer?

Comment: @RajeevSingh done. Unfortunately, I don't have resources right now to elaborate better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scheme of a solution:

1. Sort all points by their attraction value and process them one-by-one, starting with the one with lowest attraction.
2. For each point you have to quickly calculate sum of distances to all previously added points. That can be done using any online Range Sum Query problem solution, like segment tree or BIT. Key idea is that all points to the left are really not different and sum of their coordinates is enough to calculate sum of distances to them.
3. For each newly added point you just multiply that sum of distances (obtained on step 2) by point's attraction value and add that to the answer.

Intuitive observations that I made in order to invent this solution:

1. We have two "bad" functions here (somewhat "discrete"): `max` and modulo (in distance).
2. We can get rid of `max` by sorting our points and processing them in a specific order.
3. We can get rid of modulo if we process points to the left and to the right separately.
4. After all these transformations, we have to calculate something which, after some simple algebraic transformations, converts to an online RSQ problem.

Answer (score -1):

An algorithm of:

> O(N<sup>2</sup>)

is optimal, because you need the actual distance between all possible pairs.

Comment: It may be possible to avoid O(N^2) work by making use of averages and maybe standard deviation (consider that if A's attraction value is max, `A = (n-1)*average distance from A*Attraction_val_A`). Your proof would need a bit more work to convince me.

Comment: You basically claimed that because problem's statement contains "every pair" then the algorithm should be at least Ω(n^2). This is blatantly wrong and it's not how lower-bound proofs work. For example, there is a linear algorithm for the following problem: "sum of multiples of all pairs of numbers in an array"

Comment: @yeputons no of course not! You are right, updated. Dukeling I see your point. Hmm

Comment: @gsamaras I do not see how the new version is different. Your claim "you have to examine all possible pairs" is incorrect. The problem is defined in terms of "all possible pairs", but some math tricks _may_ turn it into a formula which is easier to calculate. One of them is suggested by Dukeling .